# PHP: replacement for DateTime object

Tags: php, datetime

The server that I have my sited hosted is on PHP5.12.14, and I have an error when I run the DateTime object from PHP5.3

```
# DateTime::add — Adds an amount of days, months, years, hours, minutes and seconds to a DateTime object
$date = new DateTime($item_user['mem_updated']);

# add a day to the object
$date -> add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
```

the error,

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::add() in /homepages/xxx.php on line xx
```

So, I have look for the other solutions rather than sticking to PHP5.3's DateTime object. How can I write the code to replace the code above?

basically I have this date and time data (for instance - `2011-01-21 02:08:39`) from the mysql database, and I just need to add 1 day or 24 hours to that date/time, then passing it into a function below,

```
$time_togo = time_togo($date -> format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

thanks.

Comment: You might considering upgrading PHP if you have control over the server, harassing those who do have control over the server to do it for you, or seeking new hosting.

Comment: yea I am seeking a new hosting. hate the current hosting company. out dated. bad services. I won't recommend anyone this lousy hoster which is 1&1!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strtotime would work

```
$timestamp = strtotime($item_user['mem_updated']);    
$time_togo = date("Y-m=d H:i:s", strtotime("+1 Day", $timestamp));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$new_tstamp = strtotime($date.'+1WEEK');
$new_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $new_tstamp);
```

In other words, [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) lets you use date expressions like `+1DAY`, `+1MONTH` and so on.

The above will work for date string (e.g.: 2010-01-01). If your original date is a Unix timestamp, you can still use `strtotime`, although a bit differently:

```
$new_tstamp = strtotime('+1WEEK', $timestamp);
```