# YiiBase::include(DateTime.php) :failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, yii

This error is generated when I use default new **DateTime()** function

`ERROR:" YiiBase::include(DateTime.php) [<a href='function.YiiBase-include'>function.YiiBase-include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory "`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: replacement for DateTime object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764034/php-replacement-for-datetime-object)

Answer (score 1):

[DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) is available on PHP>=5.2.0, you are running an older version of PHP. This has nothing to do with Yii.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Yii::import('DateTime');
```

Comment: In to which file i have to add this line?